# Software to rip CD during playback?

Tags: windows, audio, mp3, media-player, ripping

Is it possible for me to play an audio CD and ***at the same time*** (i.e. concurrently with the playback) rip/convert the played tracks to MP3? If yes, how can I do this on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Use foobar2000. This ability [is already built-in](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Ripping_CDs_with_Foobar2000#Drive_Settings).

1. Download & install [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/)
2. Go to File → Open audio CD → Drive settings and enable *Limit drive speed while reading*
3. Click Rip and set up your desired MP3 settings such as tags and destination folder
4. Click Play

[image]

Comment: Can it rip/convert *during playback*?

Comment: @Karan Yes, I tested if before posting. Thats why I mentioned the "Limit drive speed option". Without that option enabled, its working too, but not very well.

Comment: Nice, didin't know foobar could do that.

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems e.g. [Windows Media Player has such a feature](http://theminiaturespage.com/plus/msg.mv?id=151030) <sup>([thanks @cbabb!](https://superuser.com/a/618896/12184))</sup>. Although not really freeware/open-source, so the question's still open.

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is off-topic so I edited your question accordingly. Why does freeware/open source matter? If you're using Windows then WMP is available to you by default.